# JavaFX drag adjustable Label like Slider

Tags: java, javafx

> Edit:Code is available on
>   github(https://github.com/goxr3plus/DragAdjustableLabel)
>
> **Question**

I made a custom control in `javaFX` which I don't know how to name it. It actually does not exist in the `javaFX` packages but I saw it in other programs like [LMMS](https://lmms.io/) where it's been used to control the volume.

> **The problem**

When the mouse is reaching the top or bottom of the **monitor screen** nothing can be done. Have a look at the code to see what I'm talking about. How to solve the problem? Feel free to edit the title to a more appropriate ones.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Robot;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FX3 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        // Root-BorderPane
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(new VolumeLabel(0, 100));
        borderPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black;");

        // Scene
        stage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 200, 200, Color.BLACK));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // TODO SpecialLabel
    class VolumeLabel extends Label {

        int screenX, screenY, previousY, minimumValue, maximumValue;

        IntegerProperty currentValue = new SimpleIntegerProperty(15);

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public VolumeLabel(int minimumValue, int maximumValue) {

            this.minimumValue = minimumValue;
            this.maximumValue = maximumValue;
            textProperty().bind(currentValue.asString().concat(" %"));
            setStyle(
                    "-fx-background-color:white; -fx-text-fill:black; -fx-padding:-2 8 -2 8;  -fx-background-radius: 15; -fx-font-size:20; -fx-cursor:open-hand;");

            // MouseListeners
            setOnMousePressed(m -> {
                screenX = (int) m.getScreenX();
                screenY = (int) m.getScreenY();
                    //setCursor(Cursor.NONE);          //Uncommend this line to make the cursor invisible
            });

            setOnMouseDragged(m -> {
                setCurrentValue(
                        getCurrentValue() + (m.getScreenY() == previousY ? 0 : m.getScreenY() > previousY ? -1 : 1));
                previousY = (int) m.getScreenY();
            });

            setOnMouseReleased(m -> {
                // When the mouse is released -> move it to the initial position
                try {
                    new Robot().mouseMove(screenX, screenY);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
            });
        }

        /**
         * Returns the Current Value of VolumeLabel
         * 
         * @return
         */
        public int getCurrentValue() {
            return currentValue.get();
        }

        /**
         * Setting the Current Value of VolumeLabel
         * 
         * @param value
         */
        public void setCurrentValue(int value) {
            //System.out.println("Value:" + value + ", CurrentValue:" + currentValue.get());
            if (value >= minimumValue && value <= maximumValue)
                currentValue.set(value);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"nothing can be done"_, should the slider _not_ work when the mouse leaves the screen?

Comment: Basically i am hiding the mouse to not be shown.I want when the user presses into the control and drags up the value is increasing by 1 for every pixel.When he drags down to decrease by 1.It works but when the mouse reaches the top or bottom of the screen when still pressed it lags.For example if the value is decreased until 30 and the mouse is at the bottom of screen it will never go 0.I want the user not to have this lag.I have used this contol in other non java programs and i am trying to implement it..

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not having this problem. I can drag the mouse off of the screen and the value still keeps changing.

Comment: For example if your screen height is 1000 drag the window of the app to 850 ,then try dragging the mouse down in the contol.For me when it reaches the bottom it just stop working.I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you were talking about the App screen, not the actually computer screen ;). Sorry

Comment: @Jorn Vernee I have a solution for this question.I will post it on GitHub.The problem is i not a good name for the component above...Any ideas how to name it(i thought `InvisibleSlider`) ? :).

Comment: How about `DragAdjustableLabel`?

Comment: @Jorn Vernee Perfect Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the answer(the code also in on [github](https://github.com/goxr3plus/DragAdjustableLabel)):

```
import java.awt.Robot;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Screen;

/**
 * A custom Node which is working like a Slider. <br>
 * <b>!</b> When you hold the mouse on it and drag upside the value is
 * increased. <br>
 * <b>!</b> When you hold the mouse on it and drag down side the value is
 * decreased.
 * 
 * <br>
 * Usage:
 * 
 * <pre>
 * <code>
*     //initialize
*     DragAdjustableLabel dragAdjustableLabel = new DragAdjustableLabel(10, 0, 100);
*     
*     //add it for example to a BorderPane
*     primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(dragAdjustableLabel)));
 *</code>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @author GOXR3PLUS
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class DragAdjustableLabel extends Label {

    // Variables
    private int screenX;
    private int screenY;
    private int previousY;
    private int minimumValue;
    private int maximumValue;

    /**
     * The current value of the DragAdjustableLabel
     */
    private IntegerProperty currentValue;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param minimumValue
     *            Minimum Value that the slider can have
     * @param maximumValue
     *            Maximum Value that the slider can have
     */
    public DragAdjustableLabel(int currentValue, int minimumValue, int maximumValue) {

        this.currentValue = new SimpleIntegerProperty(currentValue);
        this.minimumValue = minimumValue;
        this.maximumValue = maximumValue;

        // Add a costume style class
        this.getStyleClass().add("drag-adjustable-label");
        setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);

        textProperty().bind(this.currentValue.asString().concat(" %"));

        // when the mouse is pressed
        setOnMousePressed(m -> {
            screenX = (int) m.getScreenX();
            screenY = (int) m.getScreenY();
            setCursor(Cursor.NONE); // comment this line to make the cursor
                                    // visible
        });

        // when the mouse is dragged
        setOnMouseDragged(m -> {

            // calculate the monitor height
            double screenHeight = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight();

            // !if the mouse has reached the the top of the monitor
            // or
            // ! if the mouse has reached the bottom of the monitor
            if (m.getScreenY() <= 0 || m.getScreenY() + 10 >= screenHeight) {
                resetMouse();
                return;
            }

            // Calculate the current value
            setCurrentValue(
                    getCurrentValue() + (m.getScreenY() == previousY ? 0 : m.getScreenY() > previousY ? -1 : 1));
            previousY = (int) m.getScreenY();
        });

        // when the mouse is released
        setOnMouseReleased(m -> {
            resetMouse();
            setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reset the mouse to the default position(which is the center of the
     * element)
     * 
     * @param x
     * @param y
     */
    private void resetMouse() {
        try {
            new Robot().mouseMove(screenX, screenY);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the current value
     * 
     * @param value
     */
    public void setCurrentValue(int value) {

        // if the value is between the limits
        if (value >= minimumValue && value <= maximumValue)
            currentValue.set(value);
    }

    public int getCurrentValue() {
        return currentValue.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty currentValueProperty() {
        return currentValue;
    }

}
```